# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, Das System

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, ioexception

Hello I try to run the following cmd code in eclipse:

```
 "DIR \""+DEV_HOME+"\\src\"\\*.java /b /s >> \""+DEV_HOME+"\\bin\\javaFiles.txt\""
```

In clear it looks like this:

```
DIR "D:\Thomas\Dokumente\Daten\workspace\WBRLight\src"\*.java /b /s >> "D:\Thomas\Dokumente\Daten\workspace\WBRLight\bin\javaFiles.txt"
```

But I get following error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
....
```

When I try to use the code in the cmd box, Its working fine.
My code:

```
    public void run_cmdLine(String command) {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        BufferedReader input = null;
        Process pr = null;

        pr = rt.exec(command);
        input = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `"cmd.exe /c"` at the beginning of your command string, that should do the trick.

The `/c` parameter will make the `cmd` finish and return it to the Java process.
Without it, the process will hang.

Comment: When I did this I got nothing in return.

Comment: If you're using ProcessBuilder::start instead of Runtime::exec, you need to pass the strings "cmd", "/c" and "dir" separately to the constructor.